# Add full media url in Rich text editor

Tags: content-editor, richtext-editor

We have email templates that are stored in Sitecore. We are using `Richtext` field to store html of emails. When I add images from Sitecore media library to that rich text field links are generating as

```
  <img src="-/media/Id.ashx?la=en-gb" alt="email-header" width="600" height="149">
```

because of this, gmail rendering the image wrong as: `http://-/media/Id.ashx?la=en-gb`

We can search and replace the html while we sending emails, but is there is a way to tell Sitecore to use full image url's for rich text field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I remember, the logic responsible for RTE links is in `ExpandLinks` processor of `renderField` pipeline:

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.ExpandLinks, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
```

```
public virtual void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) args, "args");
  if (Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditorEditing)
    return;
  args.Result.FirstPart = DynamicLink.ExpandLinks(args.Result.FirstPart, Settings.Rendering.SiteResolving);
  args.Result.LastPart = DynamicLink.ExpandLinks(args.Result.LastPart, Settings.Rendering.SiteResolving);
}
```

You could write your own logic here to make sure that links include host name as well.

You can also update `LinkProvider` method `ExpandDynamicLinks` to force it to include host names:

```
public virtual string ExpandDynamicLinks(string text, bool resolveSites)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) text, "text");
  LinkProvider.LinkParser linkParser = this.CreateLinkParser();
  UrlOptions defaultUrlOptions = this.GetDefaultUrlOptions();
  defaultUrlOptions.SiteResolving = resolveSites;

  defaultUrlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true; // <---

  return linkParser.ExpandDynamicLinks(text, defaultUrlOptions);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want Sitecore to expand those links for you in custom code, you can run something like that:

```
protected virtual string RunPipeline(Field field)
{
    using (new SiteContextSwitcher(SiteContext.GetSite("website")))
    {
        RenderFieldArgs renderFieldArgs = new RenderFieldArgs()
        {
            Item = field.Item,
            FieldName = field.Name,
            DisableWebEdit = true
        };
        CorePipeline.Run("renderField", (PipelineArgs) renderFieldArgs);
        return renderFieldArgs.Result.FirstPart + renderFieldArgs.Result.LastPart;
    }
}

string bodyOfEmail = RunPipeline(item.Fields[FieldIds.EmailBodyField]);
```

Comment: Make sense, this might work when i render the RTE field on the page.

Comment: What i am after is html code on RTE field, i want full url's in there, is it possible to do that?

Comment: It's called while rendering any field on a page. Please be aware that it has if condition which checks  `Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditorEditing` mode and that you have to update or patch configs to replace original `ExpandLinks` with your class.

Comment: @DheerajPalagiri how do you send content of the field to the external mail system?

Comment: We are publishing this email templates to email servers on sitecore publish, email servers deal with sending the emails. So we want to publish html with full image urls to email servers?

Comment: As a string bodyOfEmail = item[FieldIds.EmailBodyField];

Comment: I've added code to the answer describing how to tell Sitecore to expand the value of the field in custom c# code. Not sure if this is exactly what you need but should point you in the right direction. I don't think you can store expanded values in the fields as that would break all the functionality for tracking links (e.g. for broken links) and multisite links.

Comment: All ExpandDynamicLinks does is changed url's to "/-/media/emails/header.jpg?la=en-gb" even though i passed in defaultUrlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;

Comment: It might be because i am on publish end event, sitecore could not able to get hostname? as when i checked WebUtil.GetHostName() method returned empty string. may be includeServerUrl does the same?